# One Xcode project using another without making a static library

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I just banged my head for a while and figured out a solution, but I want to make sure that I'm doing things right and that I actually know what I'm doing (I'm pretty sure I never know what I'm doing :)

I have two projects that I've been working on, each offering different functionality. I want one project (A) to be able to use the functionality of the other (B). I tried going about it by creating a workspace and putting both projects into it, but I couldn't "see" project B's files from project A (autocomplete after #import did work, but it gave a compiler error). So I tried adding it as a "sub-project" and found the same. I figured this would be easy, but guess not.

What I ended up doing was creating a new project (C) as a "Cocoa Touch Static Library" project, and put my files from Project B into it. I built it.

I then went back to project A and added project C into it as a sub-project.

Then I added the path on the filesystem of project C into the User Header Search Paths setting under Build Settings of project A.

Then I added the .a file from Project C into the Link Binary with Libraries section of Project A.

Then it worked.

But honestly I have no idea what the meaning of a static library is.

Is all this necessary? Or is there an easier way to just integrate two projects (without me having to copy the files from one project to another)?

Thanks in advance!

Jon

Comment: this might be a good question, as static libs and including Xcode projects in other projects is an important topic. Could you clean it up and remove all the personal stuff and random doubts so that it doesn't get closed, please?

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with workspaces. What I do is have three projects in the workspace. One with no targets just to hold the generic classes. A second for my iOS target Project. And a third for mac. Keep the original files in the one with no target, then drag the files to the other two projects that creates references, so when you edit one it changes all three.